# How can I set tinymce's source code view to use a monospace font?

Tags: tinymce-4

In tinymce's source code view how can I set it to use a monospace font when displaying the HTML?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following style in the page that was hosting tinymce

```
textarea.mce-textbox {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```